# AdMob Banner is shown behind a View?

Tags: android, youtube-api, admob, android-framelayout

Hi I am using AdMoB for showing banner ad in YouTube app which retrieves Video From Channel . For showing ad I used Java Code rather than XML. Now I am facing one problem which is my Banner is shown behind the Videos after the gets loaded. Can someone please help me to find out a way to show the ad front of the Videos. This is the code i used

```
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "caXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        layout.addView(adView);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams adsParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: Why you don't use XML?

Comment: How do i do that ?Can You please explain. My FrameLayout is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way.

This is the xml code of the banner, you can place it wherever you want in your activity xml layout:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/banner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adUnitId="YOUR UNIT ID HERE"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true"/>
```

Then inside `<application>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` declare the AdActivity:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

And finnaly get the reference on your activity of banner and start request ads from google:

```
AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.banner);
ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: I see an error. I put this in FrameLayout and it say the following The 
following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/banner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adUnitId="YOUR UNIT ID HERE"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:loadAdsOnCreate="true"/>
</FrameLayout>

Comment: The code is right, don't understand why gives you this error, it gives me the same on my ADT, by the way it's an error of Interface Builder... try to run it, this should work.

Comment: I used this code.Its working but still facing Overlapping problem.

Answer (score 0):

What layout are you using? To get ads on top of my Libgdx projects, I had to use a RelativeLayout and specify put things together in a specific order. Here's an example from my code:

```
// Create the main/content layout
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

// This is just a View that LibGDX draws into, it could be any View.
View gameView = initializeForView(new SuperAwesomeGameIMade(AndroidLauncher.this)); 

// Add it to the new content layout.
layout.addView(gameView);

// Create and setup the AdMob View
mAdView = new AdView(AndroidLauncher.this);
mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
mAdView.setAdUnitId("your ad unit here");

// Create the ad load request using the AdRequest Builder
AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("your test device ID so you don't get banned!");
mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Change to View.Visible to show ads
mAdView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

// Setup the AdView with new layout params so it can "float" on the other one.
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
layout.addView(mAdView, adParams);

// Set the content view as this new relative layout
setContentView(layout);
```

Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I am using framelayout.

Comment: If you want the ads to show on top of your other views, you'll have to use a RelativeLayout. A FrameLayout won't let you overlap views like that. That's what you're trying to do, right?

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to using framelayout?